# Why is the long-term return (3+ years) of German index funds lower than that of many developed countries?

Tags: etf, funds

As in the topic. Would for example lower volatility justify lower return, (if the German funds are less volatile in the first place?).

Perhaps it's due to the German https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittelstand not being traded on the exchange? Any level materials which would help me understand this would be helpful, I have no problem with reading research papers type of material as well.

Comment: Hi, which index (funds) are you referring to?

Comment: Comment A. 3 years is too short a time period to be considered "long term returns", anything can happen in 3 years. To me long term returns means > 10 (or 20) years. Comment B. Returns vary among countries and it may be difficult to explain why this is so and whether it will continue, so for a german investor diversification across all EUR based stock markets makes sense to me, rather than only buying DAX.

Comment: Comment C. Maybe German companies are not run in the interest of shareholders, but customers, employees and bank lenders have a higher priority in the companies policies.